# nginx as reverse proxy for multiple domains and multiple containers

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, multiple-domains

I have nginx, certbot and spring boot applications all running as docker containers, configured in one docker-compose.yml.

I use the following nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sub1.domain.de;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    http2 on;
    server_name sub1.domain.de;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.domain.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.domain.de/privkey.pem;

    ssl_buffer_size 8k;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://container1:8080;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
  add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
        #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
        # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications
    }

    root /var/www/html;
       index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   }




server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sub2.domain.de;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    http2 on;
    server_name sub2.domain.de;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.domain.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.domain.de/privkey.pem;

    ssl_buffer_size 8k;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://bcontainer2:8081;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
        #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
        # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications
    }

    root /var/www/html;
       index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   }
```

SSL certificates are for both domains but are named like the first domain.
When trying to reach sub1.domain.de I get a 502, bad gateway. What am I missing here?
I can reach my container2 via the ip-adress:8081 though.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is having the same troubles, here is my solution, which worked fine for me:

in the docker-compose.yml you have to map your containers to different ports. That's what I already did, you can check the file in my first post. So this file stays the same.

In the nginx.conf though you have to address the container with it corresponding **intern** port. Meaning in my case (two containers, both are listening to port 8080 internally) the proxy_pass has to direct to "container_name:8080" in both cases. I first thought it has to be the host port, which is not the case.

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sub1.domain.de;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    http2 on;
    server_name sub1.domain.de;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.domain.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.domain.de/privkey.pem;

    ssl_buffer_size 8k;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://container1:8080;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
  add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
        #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
        # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications
    }

    root /var/www/html;
       index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   }




server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sub2.domain.de;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    http2 on;
    server_name sub2.domain.de;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.domain.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.domain.de/privkey.pem;

    ssl_buffer_size 8k;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://bcontainer2:8080;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
        #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
        # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications
    }

    root /var/www/html;
       index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   }
```